# how to add Back button to go back to previous MonoTouch storyboard view?

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, storyboard, monodevelop

In my Xamarin Studio C# MonoTouch storyboard, I have several views and each one has a button to do a modal seque to common view call "ultrasound".

How do I add a Back button to Ultrasound view that will go back to previous view?

I sequed each view by modal to the Ultrasound view.
I added the Ultrasound Back button wired to method button_ultrasound_back, but nothing happens:

Ultrasound_Controller.m
- (IBAction)button_ultrasound_back:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

When I try moving the popViewControllerAnimated line into Ultrasound_Controller.cs, then the "self" causes an error.

And, if I change the seques from other view to Ultrasound view from modal to push, then Ultrasound view crashes app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the push segue as apposed to a modal. Push requires you to have a UINavigationController and you first view set as its initial view controller. Once you have done this back buttons happen for free, no need to code them yourself.

[This is a good intro into Storyboards.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) It is Obj-C but easy to follow.

Comment: Cool!  I tried this in a new app and it's great.  But, my job is to add an Ultrasound page to an existing app with nothing but View Controllers, not one Nav Controller in the whole litter.  Is it possible hack a back button on my page to go back to the previous View Controller that sequed to my Ultrasound page?

Comment: SOLUTION:  All I need to do to correct my client's app is add a Nav View and make it the initial view...kind of like just adding nav as an abstraction layer.   Thanks so much, Blounty!  have a virtual beer on me...   :)